# make axception word source code using regex

Tags: java, regex

my program should detected method or constructor with source code java.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

class cek extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JTextArea area=new JTextArea("",5,5);
    JTextArea comment=new JTextArea("",5,5);
    JButton button;
    JScrollPane scrollPane,comment2,kelas2,ori2,tipe2;
    public cek()
    {   
        super("example");
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(area);
        button=new JButton("button");
        comment.setEditable(false);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        setLocation(0,200);
        setSize(1000,500);
        setLayout(null); 
        scrollPane.setBounds(10,10,467,417);
        comment2=new JScrollPane(comment);
        comment2.setBounds(500,10,450,417);
        button.setBounds(10,430,450,25);
        add(comment2);
        add(button);
        add(scrollPane);
        show();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(button==e.getSource())
        {
            comment.setText("");
            Pattern aaa=Pattern.compile("((public |private |protected )?(String |int |char |void )?([\\w]).*[(].*[)][ ]*([{]|([\\r\\n]*).*[{]))");
            Matcher bbb=aaa.matcher(area.getText());

            int i=0;
            while (bbb.find()) 
            {
                comment.setText(comment.getText() + bbb.group() + "\n");
            }
            Pattern a=Pattern.compile("[{]");
            Matcher b=a.matcher(comment.getText());
            comment.setText(b.replaceAll(""));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new cek();
    }
}
```

my regex

```
"((public |private |protected )?(String |int |char |void )?([\\w]).*[(].*[)][ ]*([{]|([\\r\\n]*).*[{]))"
```

but my problem why like if, for, while, calling function printed too ???

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovBnU.png

in my regex, what should i fix ???

Comment: You should use `.*` with caution.

Comment: Using regexes for analysing source code is almost always a bad idea.  It is almost inevitable that there will be obscure (or not so obscure) cases that you will get wrong.  For example, stuff in comments or strings, or ... people using Unicode escapes in strange and obscure ways.

Comment: So my answer to *"what should i fix???"* would be to throw away your analysis code, find an existing Java parser / source code analyser library, and implement your analyser based on that.  (Or if you are up for some interesting work, develop a parser from scratch using (say) Javacc or Antlr.)

Comment: this project for my thesis, and this is must using regex.

i mean where from my regex must fix ???

Comment: if it's for your thesis, "must use regex" is almost certainly not true, because we don't use regular expressions to parse grammars. They are heavily researched, and *we know they can't be used for that purpose*. Your prof should know that (if they don't, you need to talk to them), so scrap this code, and instead either use a library for parsing java grammar, or write a proper grammar parsing DFA yourself.

Comment: @uwong15 talk to your advisor about the possibility that the Java constructors are not a regular language.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to arrange the capture groups a little better.
A program like [RegexFormat](http://www.regexformat.com) can help a lot.

```
 # "(?s)(public|private|protected)\\s+(?:(static)\\s+)?(?:(String|int|char|void)\\s+)?(\\w.*?)\\((.*?)\\)\\s*.*?{"

 (?s)                     # Modifier dot-all
 (                        # (1 start), Access, required
      public 
   |  private
   |  protected 
 )                        # (1 end)
 \s+ 
 (?:
      ( static )          # (2), Storage, optional
      \s+ 
 )?
 (?:
      (                   # (3 start), Type, optional
           String
        |  int
        |  char
        |  void 
      )                   # (3 end)
      \s+ 
 )?
 ( \w .*? )               # (4), Name, required

 \(                       # '('
 ( .*? )                  # (5), Parameters 
 \)                       # ')'
 \s* .*? {                # '{'
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 551 , len 19 ) 
public cek()
    {  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 551 , len 6 ) 
public  
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 558 , len 3 ) 
cek  
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 562 , len 0 )  EMPTY 

==============================

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 1125 , len 49 ) 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 1125 , len 6 ) 
public  
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 1132 , len 4 ) 
void  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 1137 , len 15 ) 
actionPerformed  
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 1153 , len 13 ) 
ActionEvent e  

=============================

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 1789 , len 44 ) 
public static void main(String[]args)
    {  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 1789 , len 6 ) 
public  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 1796 , len 6 ) 
static  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 1803 , len 4 ) 
void  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 1808 , len 4 ) 
main  
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 1813 , len 12 ) 
String[]args
```