# Regex to Insert String at Certain Position of Java Method

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to add `throws java.lang.Exception` on any Java methods using sed.

For example,

`public static void main(String[] args) {`

would be replaced with:

`public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {`

I came up with a regex matching Java methods for my purposes:

`(public|static|private|protected)* (void|int|String|double|float)+\s([a-zA-Z]*)\s*\(.*\)\s*`

I know that you can use `sed s/FIND/REPLACE/g file` to replace patterns, but how can I match a Java method and insert `throws java.lang.Exception` after the closing parenthesis for parameters `)` and before the opening curly brace `{` of any Java method?

Comment: What if `throws Exception` is already there or there in next line?

Comment: Assume it's not already there.

Comment: @sln, please provide the link to that question.

Comment: @badjr - Here it is (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080896/make-axception-word-source-code-using-regex/26081765#26081765)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
sed -r 's/((public|static|private|protected|\s)*(void|int|String|double|float|\s)+\w+\([^)]*\)\s*)/\1throws java.lang.Exception / g'
```

Test:

```
echo "public static void main(String[] args) { " | sed -r 's/((public|static|private|protected|\s)*(void|int|String|double|float|\s)+\w+\([^)]*\)\s*)/\1throws java.lang.Exception / g'
```

will give output as

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
```

Comment: I got back the original string as output. Also tried to grep the regex you gave, but it didn't match.